# css z-index, content displaying behind each other

Tags: html, css

I am having a `z-index` issue. I have a couple of div that sit on top of each other, within them div there is some content which shows on mouseover. This content is currently being displayed behind the parent div.

The parent div have a `z-index: 2` as they need to be displayed above there own parent.

```
<div class="activity-display"><!--parent div z-index: 2-->
  <a href="#">Running</a><!--This is displayed on hover underneath its parent div, but gets hidden underneath the below activity-display-->
</div>
<div class="activity-display">
  <a href="#">Running</a>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a higher `z-index` to the anchor and this doesn't solve the issue

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are the elements positioned?

Comment: I would suggest adding the css as well, not just the HTML...

Answer (score 0):

When using the `z-index` property elements must be positioned.  Change the `a` tag to `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least give the elements you want to work with `z-index` a relative position, because `z-index` doesn't works on a `static` position. So really any other than the default position works.

You also don't need to rearrange children or parents elements, because children elements will always be over the parent. In other words, a child element will always have a `z-index + 1` relative to the parent.

Answer (score -1):

Please make a fiddle, so that we can help.

Also, some points to keep in mind, z-index works for elements `position` `absolute`.